# How to dynamically add css class to the input

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

```
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="i2">
</div>

<div id="confirm_pwd_item" class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="i2">
</div>
```

my way

```
$('input[confirm_password]').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('input propertychange',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if($('input[name=password]').val() !== $('input[name=password_confirmation]').val()){
                $("#confirm_pwd_item").addClass('has-error');
            }
            else{
                $("#confirm_pwd_item").removeClass('has-error');
            }
        },100)
    })
})
```

I'm just getting started with this framework.

I want to add `has-error` to input, if the password and confirm password are not equal.

However, this is not good way.

If not setTimeout function:

[image]

Comment: why this setTimeout()?

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('input[name="password_confirmation"]').change(function(){
    var prevPass = $('input[name="password"]').val();
    if($(this).val() != prevPass){
      $(this).addClass('has-error');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="i2">
</div>

<div id="confirm_pwd_item" class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="i2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type=password]").keyup(function(){
  var pass=$('#i2').val();
  var cpass=$('#ci2').val();
  if(pass!=cpass){
    $('input[type=password]').addClass('has-error');
  }else{
    $('input[type=password]').removeClass('has-error');
  }
});
```

```css
.has-error{
  border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="i2">
</div>

<div id="confirm_pwd_item" class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="ci2">
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/Events/blur) event and in jQuery you may use [toggleClass( className, state )](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state).

The 'has-error' class must be toggled on the corresponding div.

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name="password_confirmation"]').on('blur', function (e) {
    var pwd = $('input[name="password"]').val();
    var confirmPwd = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('has-error', pwd != confirmPwd);
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="i1">
</div>

<div id="confirm_pwd_item" class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
    <label for="i2" class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input confirm_password type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="i2">
</div>
```